# Detect 'bring to front' event?

Tags: iphone, events, multitasking

How can I detect a 'bring to front' event for a background running application in iPhone4 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;` will be called without either of the following getting called.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```